# How to add temporary data using a wizard?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, wizard

I am using a Wizard control to capture users vehicles they own.

Stage 1 - Captures users name, address etc
Stage 2 - Captures **only one** vehicle (one vehicle consists of reg, model, mileage and manufacturer)
Stage 3 - Gives a summary of the details entered and saves the record when they click finish.

I would now like to capture **multiple vehicles** at stage 2.

Since the record is saved at stage 3 my guess is i need someway of storing each vehicle at stage 2 (which the user can view and edit if required before saving the record) and then passing all temporarily saved vehicles to my method at stage 3 to save it against the user.

How could i approach this? My concern with my research is that most of the methods available dont show how to store each vehicle temporarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Session variable to store the value if you are using the web application otherwise cache is also useful container. If your wizard is single page with multiple form you can also use the hidden field or viewState. Have a class with all the properties you want to store and use the class to put in the Session

```
     public class MyData
     {
         public string Name;
         public string Address;
     }
```

In the first part of wizard do like this then once value is populated store in the Session before moving to next page. In next page so like this

```
       MyData myData = (MyData]Session["myData"];
       //again update rest of the data from current page and 
       Session["myData"] = myData;
       //Go to next page
```

Comment: Are there any examples i could use for reference as i think your on the right lines but i need a little extra knowledge in how to proceed with this?

Comment: Thanks again. Although i understand that part, the area im confused with is with stage 2. Currently the page allows only one vehicle to be entered by the form of textboxes, dropdowns etc. Therefore 1. How could i allow multiple vehicles to be entered? 2. Its this data that i would need to then insert individually into the "Vehicles table"

Comment: Create a Vehicle class with associated property and have MyData having List<Vehicle> myVehicles = new List<Vehicle>